# Question about the Smith normal form of a matrix over the field of integers

Tags: matrices

I understand that I would need to perform elementary row and column operations. So for a matrix
$M =
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array}$

am I correct in saying that it cannot be reduced further than $M =
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array}$?
Same thing with any diagonal matrix say $M =
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 5 \\
\end{array}$ to begin with, it cannot be reduced further, right? Appreciate any hint. I was just introduced to normal forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smith normal form of
$\pmatrix{2&0\\0&5}$ is $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&10}$. More generally, the SNF of
$\pmatrix{a&0\\0&b}$ is $\pmatrix{\gcd(a,b)&0\\0&\text{lcm}(a,b)}$.

With $\pmatrix{2&0\\0&5}$ you can add column $2$ to column $1$ to get
$\pmatrix{2&0\\5&5}$ and then you can reduce the first column via row operations
to $\pmatrix{1\\0}$. The second column will then be $\pmatrix{*\\\pm10}$
and one finally gets to $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&10}$.

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!